# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server new WordPress install

Tags: wordpress

After a "manual" install of WordPress on my host iPage. I was able to setup the database and looks like I have access to everything but my home url. So my [www.homeurl.com](http://www.homeurl.com) has the message ***Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server*** I have access to all the backend, I have access to [www.homeurl.com/hello-dolly](http://www.homeurl.com/hello-dolly), I don't have any plugins active. I haven't made any changes at all being a fresh install. What I did so far: removed the .htaccess and create a new one going to settings/permalinks and save to create  a new .htaccess. File permissions via ftp 755 to all directories, 644 to all files except wp-config.php (440). Now I have no more ideas on what to do

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved by including `DirectoryIndex index.php` on top of my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Go into dB wp-options table and make sure the site urls are set correctly.

Comment: I checked and both siteurl  and home has the correct domain

Comment: Did you change the urls at the bottom of config.php and go into admin dashboard to make sure the homepage is set correctly?

Comment: I didn't change any url in config.php except the dB info to install it. The admin dashboard>Settings>Genereal urls are correct

Comment: btw if I try to access www.homeurl.com/wp-admin/ I get the same 403 Forbidden message, but if I go using  www.homeurl.com/wp-admin/index.php it works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disabled the `ModSecurity` rule `CWAF` in Plesk and the 403 error on `/wordpress/wp-admin/` was gone.